# Is it recommended in Buddhism to know people from other nations and learn their languages

Tags: language

In Islamic quran, we Muslims are asked to know people from other nations and following other religions, we are recommended to learn their languages. Allah said: "O Mankind, We have created you from a male and a female, and made you into peoples and tribes that you may know one another." Is there any recommendations in the Buddhism that tells the same? especially for languages learning?

Answer (score 3):

> ...
>
> You should not cling to a regional language; you should not reject common usage.
>
> This is a summary of the analysis of non-conflict.

[Arana Vibhanga Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/7.8-Arana-Vibhanga-S-m139-piya.pdf)

A lot more discussions in [Language and Discourse](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/26.11-Language-and-discourse.-piya.pdf) by Piya Tan

Comment: Are those your words, or they are mentioned as in in any holy book please?

Comment: This is Arana Vibhanga Sutta which is part of the Majjhima Nikāya which is part of the Sutta Pitaka which in part of the [Tripitaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripi%E1%B9%ADaka)